# Finding unique ID for android phone devices

Tags: android, unique, gsm, telephonymanager

Does `TelephonyManager. getDeviceId ()` returns different ID If user changes his mobile network in settings from `GSM` to `CDMA` , `WCDMA` (or  vice versa from CDMA to GSM )  ?

Or does `TelephonyManager. getDeviceId ()` returns an `IMEI` id when network settings in mobile is set to `GSM` and `MEID or ESN` id when settings changes to `CDMA`
and so returned values from `getDeviceId()` may changes base on device settings and **can not be used to uniquely identify devices !**

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a unique ID on all devices. TelephonyManager fails on tablets and returns null, so you have to combine that result with something else, like I did.

```
public static String getDeviceID(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;

    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    return deviceUuid.toString();
}
```

Note you need to add this permission to AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: As you see title is about phone devices thus tm.getDeviceId() should not returns null.

I need to identify a device but if user changes his/her SIM card tm.getSimSerialNumber() changes. I think ANDROID_ID may changes (I am not sure) if user upgrades his android OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (specifically) you're using an unique id, but in my case I use it to identify a unique "app instalation". So it's not dependent of simCards, telephonymanager and etc.

What I did was create a unique id (when it has not been created yet) and stored it in sharedprefs:

```
private static String       uniqueID           = null;

public static String getDeviceUniqueID(Context context)
{
        if (uniqueID == null)
        {
            final String    PREF_UNIQUE_ID     = "PREF_UNIQUE_ID";
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
            if (uniqueID == null)
            {
                uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
        return uniqueID;        
}
```

**Caveats:**

- Of course it will be lost when user uninstalls the app, because sharedprefs are deleted too;
- There's a chance of a unique id to be generated for 2 different users (but are trillions or more per one).

But, as I said above: "don't know why you're using it".

It works like a charm to me this way. Perhaps it'll work for you too. Cheers.

Comment: OK, I understand. In that case my solution is not suitable.

Comment: I think you don't need a uuid. If I was doing that, I'd rely on device's Google account. Does it matter if the user changes his device? What happen if user buys a new phone? Does he have to "re-buy" everything he has bought before?